# createElement not working in IE 8 and less

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, createelement

I have been struggling with an issue and have boiled it down to IE 8 and less.  My suspicion is createElement.   Can anyone help.

This is the stripped down code to the bare minimum

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<script>
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
s.src="myscript.php";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
</script>
</head>
<body>                  
</body>
```

Comment: That script should run when the page loading is complete

Comment: How can you tell that it's not working?  Do you get errors?  How are you diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire HTML with `<html>` tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
s.src="myscript.php";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
</script>
</head>
<body>                  
</body>
</html>
```